# Default parameters and variable list

Tags: c++, list, templates, variables

I was playing with variable parameter list. Please refer the below code snippet. Here, I am trying to Print the contents of a user defined type inside Foobar.

```
template<typename T>
void Foobar(const T& obj,int nNumberofParams,...)
{  
  va_list args;  
  va_start(args,nNumberofParams);
  for(int i =0 ; i < nNumberofParams; i++)
  {  
    T val = va_arg(args,T);
    val.PrintContent();
  }
  va_end(args);
}  
//! Template Specialization for int
template<>
void Foobar(const int& ,int nNumberofParams,...)
{
va_list args;
va_start(args,nNumberofParams);
cout << "Foobar specialize for int called" << endl;
for(int i =0 ; i < nNumberofParams; i++)
{
    int val = va_arg(args,int);
    cout << val << endl;
}
va_end(args);
```

}

In main i am doing something like this

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //! MyClass implements PrintContent
    MyClass obj,obj1(1,2,0),obj2(3,4,1),obj3,obj4(5,5,2),obj5(6,6,3);
    Foobar(obj,5,obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5);// Works fine

    //! Can't this be simpler ?
    int i = 3;
    int &j = i;
    Foobar(j,3,1,2,3);// Template specialization for int

    //! Can't this be simpler ?
    double d = 3.0;
    double& d1 = d;
    Foobar(d1,3, 1.0,2.0,3.0);// Template specialization for double

return 0;
```

}

Is it possible to have a default argument in a function that takes variable list ? It yes, then how to do it ?

Comment: You cannot really use variadic functions with class objects. That is not required to work (even if it might happen to work with some compilers).

Comment: It doesn't work with g++ or clang.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, you can use variadic templates.

In C++03, why don't you make an ordinary first parameter of the correct type and have a variable parameter list from the second parameter on instead of introducing a "dummy" parameter? Or call the specialization of the template like `Foobar<int>` ?

Comment: You can't have a variable parameter list from the second parameter on here. You can have a variable parameter list from the third parameter on.

Comment: Except it won't work. Variadic functions use ancient C (pre-standard C) argument passing: integers, doubles, pointers, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in C++11: http://ideone.com/9CGz4

```
void Foobar() {}

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void Foobar(const First &val, Rest... args)
{  
    val.PrintContent();
    Foobar(args...);
}

template<typename... Rest>
void Foobar(const int val, Rest... args)
{  
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
    Foobar(args...);
}
```

As of C++03: http://ideone.com/36lA5

```
template<typename T> 
void Print(T val) {
  cout << val << endl;
}

struct MyStruct {
  MyStruct(int a) : b(a) {}
  void print() { cout << "MS: " << b << endl; }
  int b;
};

void Print(MyStruct &val) {
 val.print();
}

template<typename T>
void Foobar(int nNumberofParams, ...) {
  va_list args;  
  va_start(args,nNumberofParams);
  for(int i =0 ; i < nNumberofParams; i++)
  {  
    T val = va_arg(args,T);
    Print(val);
  }
  va_end(args);
}
```

and then just specialize `Print` to match your needs.

`Foobar<MyStruct>(2, MyStruct(1), MyStruct(2));`

or even

`Foobar<MyStruct>(2, 1, 2);`

It is a little simpler.

Comment: Your c++ 03 `void Foobar(int nNumberofParams,...)` won't work.

Comment: Interestingly, if you have both the templates that is 1. template<typename T>
void Foobar(const T& obj,int nNumberofParams,...) and 2 template<typename T>
void Foobar(int nNumberofParams,...) then it shows error

Comment: Yep, you're right - there is no way compiler can specialize this function if there is no proper parameter for it. You can still do this: http://ideone.com/dD1cx

Comment: Now make that work for MyClass. You can't because the standard doesn't support what the questioner is trying to do.

Comment: It is working for `MyStruct`. Did you even saw how I edited the answer? Check http://ideone.com/VgSfF